# Create image (EBS AMI) takes forever - possibly caused MySQL Server to break?

Tags: mysql, centos, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I'm trying to create an EBS AMI from my running EC2 instance to reuse my LAMP fully configured (for my needs). I got my website up and running yesterday on this EC2 instance my MySQL was working fine until this morning (it's not that difficult to install LAMP thanks to yum so I can't see how I could go wrong with this; having said that, it's always difficult for one to realise his own errors)

1. I have seen "Loading, please wait ..." for a few hours now.
   **How do I know whether this is completed or its progress?**
   [image]
2. Shortly after I tried to create the AMI image from my EC2 instance, I encountered database connection error

> can't connect to local mysql server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

I was able to restart mysqld at first.
But database connection was down again.
This time, I could not restart mysqld anymore. It shows

> MySQL Daemon failed to start.

**Could my attempt to create the AMI by any chance cause the MySQL server to reboot or corrupt?**

I did a lot of searched and have done the following although I think I shouldn't have to do any workaround for MySQL server to work here

```
chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql/
```

I also found [this workaround](http://wordpressapi.com/2011/02/03/solved-issue-connect-local-mysql-server-socket-varlibmysqlmysql-sock-2/) but I'm very reluctant to follow due to my belief and the fact I would need to understand this problem first.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Getting back to searching for a solution for the MySQL server problem ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The issue with MySQL server either resolved itself or I successfully resolved it.
It was not that difficult after all.
This issue appeared to be independent from the creating AMI process

2) The answer that I got from AWS support on how long it would take to create an AMI image from a running EC2 instance is that it depends and I have to wait for the process to complete.

1 good practice I have learnt from serverfault.com is that I should have MySQL on a separate EC2 instance or better yet, RDS and that definitely save troubles.